# Как понять алгоритмы?

Tags: циклы, алгоритм

Подскажите, как происходит вообще в голове нахождение алгоритма, то есть я не могу понять, вот есть задачи вывести на консоль звездочками фигуры (циклы, java). Как вот, если есть фигура, каков поэтапный алгоритм решения задачи. Смотрю на условия в цикле и не могу понять, как же их составляли, на основе чего. Не знаю, как описать. Пример вот, треугольник:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
            // Здесь условие даже немного проще
            if (k == 0 || k == i || i == count - 1) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        // Переход на следующую строку
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Написано "здесь условие намного проще", кому оно проще, когда я смотрю на треугольник в консоли на 2,3 строку, не могу понять, как.

Ну, здесь ромб:

```
int x = 11;
    int y = 11;

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {

            if(j==y/2-i||j==y/2+i||j==i-y/2||j==x-i+x/2-1)
                System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Условие `if(j==y/2-i || j==y/2+i || j==i-y/2 || j==x-i+x/2-1)`, уже на бумаге пишу, но еще труднее понять, как оно составлялось и откуда и как его искать, оно подбором составляется?

Comment: >Подскажите, как происходит вообще в голове нахождение алгоритма

ну блин, нейроны, всякие там электрохимичесмкие реакции и все такое. 


Ну а если серьезно, то вы правда думаете, что вам тут сейчас покажут волшебный способ, который в мгновение ока научит понимать алгоритмы? Это вырабатывается практикой, регулярными упражнениями, решением алгоритмических задач

Comment: @dimads попробуйте это нарисовать

Comment: Попытайтесь не чужой код разобрать, а написать свой. Начните с линий и квадрата. Потом попытайтесь понять, как нарисовать другие фигуры, даже если не выйдет - посмотрите еще раз на код, который вы привели нам в пример, поняли алгоритм? Если нет - бросаем рисование и переходим к циклам, ищите задачки (или сами придумываем), и набиваем руку циклами, в вашем случае вложенными. Снова смотрим код, примеры… Если не вышло - все по-новой!

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения, буду разбираться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всегда разбивайте задачу на несколько задач попроще. Эти задачи - на ещё более простые. Продолжайте разбиение до тех пор, пока не сможете решить полученные микрозадачи.

Рассмотрим задачу с треугольником. Нам нужно нарисовать что-то вроде этого:

```
*         // 0
**        // 1
* *       // 2
*  *      // 3
*   *     // 4
*    *    // 5
*******   // 6
```

Делать это нужно построчно. То есть получится программа

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // печатаем i-ю строку
    System.out.println();  // переходим на новую строку
}
```

Как напечатать `i`-ю строку треугольника? Ищем закономерности. Во-первых, замечаем, что длина `i`-й строки равна `i + 1`. Значит, программа выглядит так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        if (/* нужно печатать звёздочку в j-й позиции? */) {
            System.out.println("*");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Как определить, нужно ли печатать звёздочку в `j`-й позиции? Ищем закономерности в построении треугольника. Замечаем, что последняя строка полностью заполнена звёздочками, а в остальных строках звёздочки только в первой и последней позициях. Пробуем выразить это в условии:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        if (j == 0              // если мы в первой позиции
            || j == i           // или в последней позиции
            || i == count - 1   // или на последней строке
            ) {
            System.out.println("*");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

А вообще, [[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild) очень правильно сказал - практика, практика и ещё раз практика. Только решив много алгоритмических задач, вы научитесь быстро находить необходимые алгоритмы.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!